# MySQL Cluster. Have I Chosen the Wrong Data Engine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

We currently have a database running in production that's using MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB tables.

As an evaluation, I've setup a MySQL Cluster (7.3) with MySQL (5.6) which has 2 Data Nodes, 2 SQL Nodes, and 1 Mgm Node; all on separate machines. All of the tables now use NDB (ndbcluster) rather than InnoDB.

The original intention was to provide redundancy with a distributed system that could serve data globally and efficiently.

However, the efficiency (performance) is greatly impacted. Am I mistaken in thinking that multi-table queries will ever be close in performance to InnoDB?

Comment: "could serve data globally" you had your data nodes on the same local network right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only InnoDB tables in your system, I would recommend using [MySQL Galera Cluster](http://codership.com/content/using-galera-cluster) for replication. It doesn't have the same restrictions as the NDBCluster tables have in MySQL Cluster version

Comment: Percona XtraDB cluster is a good option, as well. Uses Galera under the hood.

Comment: @Tero: Have you used Galera? The issue I have with MySQL Cluster is query latency, which is a result of Sharding and Data Nodes being distributed on a network, rather than the InnoDB engine. It appears that Galera's nodes all store data on the node's file system, as a typical mysqld does. Is this correct?

Comment: @paiego that's correct. Every node in a galera cluster has all the data, and does not need to communicate with the other nodes at all on `SELECT` queries.  An isolated node, however, will by design refuse to answer queries, because it assumes its data is stale.  With 3 nodes, and a 2/1 network isolation split, the 2 work normally and the 1 will stop answering. If you really want only 2 nodes, a 3rd dummy node can be set up so that on an isolation, the server that can still see the dummy will stay online since the logic is based on a quorum... but 3 full nodes is preferable.

Comment: I have used Galera in two production servers for over a year, and it has been working fine. There were a couple of issues early on, but they were fixed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, If you want to use MySQL Cluster, you must change engine to 'ndbcluster'. InnoDB tables will be stored on SQL nodes locally.

Comment: Yes, InnoDB was the original DB's engine and I needed to change all of the tables to NDB (ndbcluster) in order for them to work in the cluster; become stored in the Data Nodes. I'm seeing a significant performance hit.